# What are these 3 Angular2 commands importing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-providers

I am studying Angular2 in ES6 JavaScript using [this sample app](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter).  Specifically, I am trying to map out the chain of dependencies starting at the root JavaScript file for the entire app, which is [boot.js](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/boot.js).  **Can someone please explain what exactly is being imported by the following three lines of `boot.js`**:

```
import { CORE_PROVIDERS } from './app/core';
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from './app/auth';
import { POSTS_PROVIDERS } from './app/posts';
```

When I navigate to the `'./app/core'`, `'./app/auth'`, and `'./app/posts'` directories in the GitHub link above, there are so many nested files in those directories that it is not clear to me what exactly is being passed into the three `..._PROVIDERS` variables by the above three commands.  Can someone else please explain this?

The complete code for `boot.js` is:

```
import './shim';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app/core/components/app/app.component';
import { APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER } from './app/core/app.routes';
import { CORE_PROVIDERS } from './app/core';
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from './app/auth';
import { POSTS_PROVIDERS } from './app/posts';

if (ENVIRONMENT === 'production') {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  FORM_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,

  APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER,
  AUTH_PROVIDERS,
  POSTS_PROVIDERS,
  CORE_PROVIDERS,

  { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
  { provide: 'ENVIRONMENT', useValue: ENVIRONMENT }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a

```
import { Something } from './one/two';
```

It will look for the `Something` identifier that was exported by the `index` file at the `two` folder.

---

In your case, when the file located at `/client/boot.js` does

```
import { CORE_PROVIDERS } from './app/core';
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from './app/auth';
import { POSTS_PROVIDERS } from './app/posts';
```

The first one looks for the exported `CORE_PROVIDERS` identifier from `/client/app/core/index.js`, [which is](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/core/index.js):

```
import { LoggedInGuard } from './guards/logged-in.guard';
import { LoggedOutGuard } from './guards/logged-out.guard';

export const CORE_PROVIDERS = [LoggedInGuard, LoggedOutGuard];
```

As you can see, it merely "re-exports" other providers, that are themselves present at other files.

The first one at [`/client/app/core/guards/logged-in.guard.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/core/guards/logged-in.guard.js) and so on.

---

By the way, this use of `index` files is a good practice, also suggested at the Angular2 style guide under [Create and Import Barrels](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#04-10).

Comment: This page should take care of all your doubts: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: Thank you and +1 for educating us with a thorough and clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

`*_PROVIDERS` exports are conventional for Angular 2 to keep several relevant providers under single constant (a rough counterpart of AngularJS modules).

These are not Angular 2 dependencies but app dependencies. They can be tracked from [index file](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/core/index.js) to [nested modules](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/client/app/core/guards/logged-in.guard.js) one by one.